# Selenium 3 python send_keys function cannot handle the "/" character

Tags: python, selenium

For example if we had some code like this

```
// textbox is some valid html textbox element
textbox.send_keys("before/after")
```

the inside of the text box would look like `afterbefore`

I'm assuming here that the `/` charter is some sort of reserved character the brings you back to the start or something. Is there the way to substitute or escape the character so that I get a `/` and not back to the front of the text?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the way `send_keys` works is it doesn't enter the character from the string but the key binded to that character based on the machine setup that you are running your tests on. So in my cause I had to simulate pressing `/` and `alt` at the same time.

```
textbox.send_keys("/") # "/" => shift back to the beginning
textbox.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL"/") # "/" => select all
textbox.send_keys(Keys.ALT "/") # "/" => "/"
```